# How to do CollisionCheck() for different types of collisions?

Tags: c#, collision-detection

I'm sure there must be an article about this somewhere in stackoverflow but I can't seem to find it...

In case there isn't such an article, I'm creating a game that has different types of collisions between gameobjects (specifically: player & monsters, bullet & player, bullet & monsters, monsters & wall, bullet & wall, player & wall). I don't have much code to show at the moment since I'm still planning on how to do it, and this will be the first time that I've ever coded a c# game.

```
class abstract GameObject {
    public Clear(){
        //Clears the object
    }
}
class Player : GameObject
class Bullet : GameObject
class Monster : GameObject

class Map {
    private List<GameObject> _objectList;    

    public CollisionCheck(GameObject incomingObj, GameObject hitObj) {
        var incRect = new Rectangle(
            incBox.Location.X, 
            incBox.Location.Y, 
            incBox.Width, 
            incBox.Height
        );
        var isCollision = incRect.Contains(hitObj.Location.X, hitObj.Location.Y);
        if (isCollision && hitObj.GetType() == typeof(Player)) {
            Map.Reset();
        }
        if (isCollision && hitObj.GetType() == typeof(Monster)) {
            incObj.Clear();        
            hitObj.Clear();
        }
        //There will be more if's for other cases
    }
}
```

So far that's all I've got for `CollisionCheck()` in `Map`. Problem is I need to do a few more if's for a few more cases. Is there a better way to do this? I can't use `&&` in a `switch` statement so I don't think `switch` would be appropriate... Do I use an `enum`? Or is there an entirely different way to do collision checking?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried [overload](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-method-overloading/)? though i'm not sure how you will call the Collision method, because, overload is not the silver bullet.. also, is this [unity](https://unity3d.com/)? if yes, please tag it.

Comment: no, I'm not using a game engine for this. Also are you suggesting me overloading the method with different types of `GameObjects`?

Comment: well, yes, something like `public CollisionCheck(Player incomingObj, Monster hitObj)`.. to reduce your `if`s and `switch`es and let the compiler resolve which method to call automatically.. though again, i'm not really sure how you will call this particular method.. in case `GameObject player = new Player()` then pass it to the first parameter of the example method, it wont resolve.